# Customizing ubercart shopping cart items

Tags: drupal, field, shopping-cart, ubercart

Does anyone know how to customize the shopping cart page for [ubercart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubercart) ([Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) 6.x)? I would like to add the SKU field in the 'desc' column under the product title and some other things.. like

Shipping Time: 2 Weeks

.

So the 'desc' column should look like this:

Product Title

SKU: Model1

Shipping Time: 2 Weeks

Much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the description field in ubercart code or not enter any discription when you create a new product.

By default product title and SKU is shown when you enter a new product.You can have a custom field for Shipping time, so that you can enter shipping time when you create new product.